# Android: Unit Testing a service

Tags: android, unit-testing, service, junit4

I'm currently trying to write an Android app using TDD. I've been given the assignment to write a service that will be very important in the application.

As for this reason I'm trying to write a proper test for the service. The Android guidelines state the following:

> The topic What To Test lists general considerations for testing Android components. Here are some specific guidelines for testing a Service:
>
> - Ensure that the onCreate() is called in response to Context.startService() or Context.bindService(). Similarly, you should ensure that onDestroy() is called in response to Context.stopService(), Context.unbindService(), stopSelf(), or stopSelfResult().
>     Test that your Service correctly handles multiple calls from Context.startService(). Only the first call triggers Service.onCreate(), but all calls trigger a call to Service.onStartCommand().
> - In addition, remember that startService() calls don't nest, so a single call to Context.stopService() or Service.stopSelf() (but not stopSelf(int)) will stop the Service. You should test that your Service stops at the correct point.
> - Test any business logic that your Service implements. Business logic includes checking for invalid values, financial and arithmetic calculations, and so forth.
>
> [Source: Service Testing | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html)

I've yet to see a proper test for these life cycle methods, multiple calls to Context.startService() etc. I'm trying to figure this out but I'm currently at a loss.

I'm trying to test the service with the ServiceTestCase class:

```
import java.util.List;

import CoreManagerService;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ServiceTestCase;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * 
 * This test should be executed on an actual device as recommended in the testing fundamentals.
 * http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#WhatToTest
 * 
 * The following page describes tests that should be written for a service.
 * http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html
 * TODO: Write tests that check the proper execution of the service's life cycle.
 * 
 */
public class CoreManagerTest extends ServiceTestCase<CoreManagerService> {

    /** Tag for logging */
    private final static String TAG = CoreManagerTest.class.getName();

    public CoreManagerTest () {
        super(CoreManagerService.class);
    }

    public CoreManagerTest(Class<CoreManagerService> serviceClass) {
        super(serviceClass);

        // If not provided, then the ServiceTestCase will create it's own mock
        // Context.
        // setContext();
        // The same goes for Application.
        // setApplication();

        Log.d(TAG, "Start of the Service test.");
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testPreConditions() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartingService() {
        getSystemContext().startService(new Intent(getSystemContext(), CoreManagerService.class));

        isServiceRunning();
    }

    private void isServiceRunning() {
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        boolean serviceFound = false;
        for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
            if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(
                    CoreManagerService.class.toString())) {
                serviceFound = true;
            }
        }
        assertTrue(serviceFound);
    }
}
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly? Should I use an activity test to test the binding of the service against?

Comment: Any update on this? I have been searching for the similar answer but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question and I think I could probably write a unit test that tests the lifecycle methods. You could probably use Broadcasts (context.sendBroadcast() and a broadcastreceiver) to send messages from the service to the test. I could maybe write one for you, though I'd have to see when I have time for that.

Comment: Well I have a sticky remote service and it runs another thread to do async task. It would be nice to test the lifecycle but what I really need is to test the thread handler. I dont see much examples on that. I'm considering creating a stub for my thread or using mock objects but I don't know how to test non-lifecycle methods in service or state change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Theres an [example using JUnit 4](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/integration/ServiceTestRuleSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/ServiceTestRuleSample/LocalServiceTest.java):

Service:

```
/**
 * {@link Service} that generates random numbers.
 * <p>
 * A seed for the random number generator can be set via the {@link Intent} passed to
 * {@link #onBind(Intent)}.
 */
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Used as a key for the Intent.
    public static final String SEED_KEY = "SEED_KEY";

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    // Random number generator
    private Random mGenerator = new Random();

    private long mSeed;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // If the Intent comes with a seed for the number generator, apply it.
        if (intent.hasExtra(SEED_KEY)) {
            mSeed = intent.getLongExtra(SEED_KEY, 0);
            mGenerator.setSeed(mSeed);
        }
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods.
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random integer in [0, 100).
     */
    public int getRandomInt() {
        return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class LocalServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public final ServiceTestRule mServiceRule = new ServiceTestRule();

    @Test
    public void testWithBoundService() throws TimeoutException {
        // Create the service Intent.
        Intent serviceIntent =
                new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), LocalService.class);

        // Data can be passed to the service via the Intent.
        serviceIntent.putExtra(LocalService.SEED_KEY, 42L);

        // Bind the service and grab a reference to the binder.
        IBinder binder = mServiceRule.bindService(serviceIntent);

        // Get the reference to the service, or you can call public methods on the binder directly.
        LocalService service = ((LocalService.LocalBinder) binder).getService();

        // Verify that the service is working correctly.
        assertThat(service.getRandomInt(), is(any(Integer.class)));
    }
}
```

Comment: @w3bMak3r fixed

Comment: what happens if you don't use a bindable service?

Comment: @JulianSuarez then you have you try something else to test your services :P

Comment: that's not a unit test

Comment: @Sepultura what do you mean?